# How do you open the blue chests?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-2-revenant-kingdom

I am only 3-4 hours in and have so far come across a few blue chest which are locked with no obvious means to open them.

I beleive I have only seen these on the overworld so far, but there may be some in the dungeons too.

How do you unlock these blue chests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening blue chests requires the "spring lock" spell. This spell is obtainable (researchable), and not a bad idea to obtain as soon as possible to avoid backtracking to open these chests.

Specifics on the requirements to obtain the Spring Lock spell (minor story/gameplay mechanic spoiler):

> In Evermore, upgrade the kingdom to level 2. Build the Evermore Spellworks, and upgrade that to level 3. Finally, research the spell development for the spring lock spell at the Spellworks. Source: https://www.primagames.com/games/ni-no-kuni-ii-revenant-kingdom/tips/how-open-blue-chests-ni-no-kuni-2-unlock

Comment: Worth pointing out that opening blue chests inside the dream doors ***doesn't*** require the spring lock spell and are opened with orbs you accumulate throughout the maze. Would be fairly annoying to find out you missed out on all of them otherwise